# Redirect domain https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com without rewrite rules just redirect in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I'm trying to redirect from https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com,

I can achieve the following task with rewrite, but only want it via redirect 301.

```
VirtualHost domain.com:80 
RewriteEngine on 
ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L] 
VirtualHost _default_:443 
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
ServerName domain.com:443 
ServerAlias www.domain.com 
DocumentRoot /var/www/html 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(.+) 
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Redirect is not working for me as I tried to redirect `/` to `https://` but its redirecting to `https://domain.com` not `https://www.domain.com`

Comment: Have you tried this : `RewriteRule ^ https://www.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: @Leogout : I don't want to use rewrite, I just want to do it via redirect if possible.

Comment: @user3355434 what is your reason for not wanting to use rewrite? You can't use Redirect to do what you want because the it doesn't take conditions. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect I mentioned that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `mod-alias (Redirect)` for this. `Rewrite` is more powerful,easier and the most common way to redirect based on conditions. Redirect will handle directories but doesn't have any conditions. Maybe you should try your rewrite rule this way instead. And with Rewrite you are doing a `301`, that is what the flag `R=301` means.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Everything like app.hostname will also go to www.hostname I think?